# For loop to fill my div box's

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

Confused on why this isnt filling my div box's with 1-28 please help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $newdiv = $('div.box').text(i);
    for (var i =2; i <28; i++) {
        $newdiv = $('div.box').text(i);
        $('div.box').append($newdiv);
    }
});
```

Comment: where you declare $newdiv you have .text(i) What's i in that case? Also please create a fiddle, and don't use variable names with $.

Comment: @radubogdan I don't see issues with using $whatever for variable names. I usually do that when caching jquery elements.

Comment: What's the actual issue? what results are you getting? by looking at your code, each time you are going through the loop, it is setting all div.box to the i value

Comment: @radubogdan Actually, it's common to use variables beginning with `$` when storing jQuery objects for later use. It helps identify which variables hold jQuery objects and which don't. It's by no means mandatory but it is a fairly common practice. Nothing wrong with it either.

Comment: There is no problem using $, but it's a bad style. Also you didn't explain what are you trying to do. But ofc it's a matter of taste.
Edit: @War10ck : I know. I don't usually mess them

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your conditions. Right now you are starting at `i=2` and ending at `i=27`. Change your for-loop to do this instead:

```
for (var i=1; i<=28; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are passed by reference. Therefore, you're changing the text of the original DOM object, ***not*** creating a new one. Try the following:

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready(function () { ... });
$(function () {
    // Create an array to store your new elements temporarily.
    var newDivs = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < 29; i++) {
        // Create your new <div> elements and push them to
        // your array. Using the following syntax for
        // creating elements allows jQuery to use
        // document.createElement internally.
        newDivs.push($('<div />', { "class": "box", "text": i }));
    }
    // Once all elements are created, append the entire
    // group to the $('div.box') element.
    $('div.box').append(newDivs);
});
```

Comment: that worked but all of the numbers are stacked on top of eachother?

Answer (score 0):

TRY this .It's tested.

```
    <pre>

<html>
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script> 
 <script>      
   $(document).ready(function () {
     for (var i=1; i <28; i++) {
      $('#box').append(i+" ");
      }
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

}
</style>
 <div id="box">
 </div>
</body>
</html>


<code>
```